# Is a countable union of nested complete metric spaces complete in this case?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry, complete-spaces

In general, it's definitely not true that the countable union of nested closed subsets of a complete metric space is complete: the union of $[1/n, 1-1/n]$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is $(0,1)$, the union of $Q_n := \left\{\frac{r}{s}\,|\, (r,s) = 1,\, n! | s\right\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ etc. However, there is a situation I'm interested in where this is the case:

Suppose $F_0, F_1, F_2,\ldots $ is a sequence of closed subsets of some complete metric space $(X,d)$ with $F_i \subseteq F_{i+1}$ and also $\text{diam}(F_i)\to \infty$ as $i\to\infty$. Then the union of the $F_i$s is closed, since any convergent sequence $(x_i)$ inside their union is bounded and so there is some $k$ such that $x_j \in F_k$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and since $F_k$ is closed, the limit $x$ of the sequence must lie inside $F_k$ and thus their union.

My question is: **is the corresponding statement true for complete metric spaces?** This might be really obvious but I can't tell if what I said above can be converted into a proof of the following statement:

*Suppose $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots $ is a sequence of nested complete metric spaces, in the sense that there is a distance preserving function $\sigma_{i,j}:X_i\to X_j$ for any $i<j$ (and we can assume WLOG that the underlying sets have $X_i\subseteq X_j$), such that $\text{diam}(X_i)\to \infty$ as $i\to \infty$. Then the "union space", with underlying set $\bigcup_{i\geq 1} X_i$ and metric inherited from each $X_i$, is complete.*

Comment: The statement about closed sets is not true. For example, if $X = \Bbb{R}$ and $F_i = [1/(i+1), i+1]$, then the sets are closed, nested, and with divergent diameter. But, the union is $(0, \infty)$, which is not closed.

Comment: To make the statement about closed sets true, you should assume that locally, the sequence $(F_k)_k$ is eventually constant, i.e. every $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $F_k\cap U=F_{k+1}\cap U$ for all sufficiently large $k$. The corresponding statement about metric spaces follows, since you can just consider $X_i$ as subspaces of the completion of the direct limit.

Comment: If you do manage to fix the statement for families of closed subsets of complete metric spaces, you can rest assured that it will hold for families of complete spaces. The reason is, the union space is a metric space, and hence has a completion. Complete spaces are closed in whatever space they're embedded in, so a nested family of complete spaces can be viewed as a nested family of closed subsets of the completion of their union space.

Comment: @TheoBendit, tomasz: thank you both! I realise that tomasz's suggestion does appear to be the natural salvage-attempt of the proposition but unfortunately this statement doesn't quite work for the application I was hoping. Also thank you to both for pointing out the trick for transferring statements about closed sets into statements about complete metric spaces via the completion! This discussion made me realise something though: in my application the completion of the direct limit will work just as well, so I can just take that!